# Calling a Oracle function using Spring StoredProcedure class

Tags: spring

I have an Oracle function as below:

```
FUNCTION GetDetails (Acct_No IN VARCHAR2, Qtype IN VARCHAR2, MaxRecs IN NUMBER DEFAULT 500, Debug IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0, p_ErrorCode OUT NUMBER) RETURN SYS_Refcursor
```

I am using a Spring `StoredProcedure` class to call this function as below:

```
public GetDetailsStoredProcedure(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, int type) {        

        super(jdbcTemplate, "GetDetails");         

        RowMapper<?> rowMapper = new CadreAuthorizationRowMapper();

        setFunction(true);

        declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet(Constants.FUN_OUT_RESULT_LIST, rowMapper));

        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Constants.FUN_IN_CARD_NUMBER, OracleTypes.VARCHAR));        
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Constants.FUN_IN_REQ_TYPE, OracleTypes.VARCHAR));        
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Constants.FUN_IN_MAX_REC, OracleTypes.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Constants.FUN_IN_DEBUG, OracleTypes.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(Constants.FUN_OUT_ERROR_CODE, OracleTypes.NUMERIC));

        compile();    
    }
```

The issue I am having is, Spring not taking all the DeclaredParameters to prepare the SQL String, its skipping one of the DeclapredParameter as its using that to define the return value... so I end up having one less "?" in the Callable SQL string.

This is like any normal Oracle function which returns a refcursor as well a OUT param and it takes in 4 IN params.